# Dividir meu cod HTML em HTML's separados

Tags: html5

Bom  dia.

Sou aluno de sistemas pra internet e sou iniciante.
Meu site está legal mas está difícil administrar os conteúdos pois ele está muito grande.

Gostaria de tipo escreve o coarrousel em HTML separado e chama-lo, depois modal, e assim por diante.

Ae editaria os conteúdos separado.

Como faço pra chamar o HMTL e incorporar na pág index?

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem arquivos html e deseja inserir eles dentro de outra página, você pode utilizar o Jquery para isso. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $('#inserir_pagina').load("meu_arquivo.html");

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="inserir_pagina"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não conseguir não chama adicionei o script

O Jqueryy eu já chamo   

     <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         
         $('#inserir_pagina').load("contato.html");
      
      });
      </script>

   depois coloquei a div onde quero chamar o outro html
 <div id="inserir_pagina"></div>

   Mas não funcionou


    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>